# struts2 ajax jsonexception

Tags: ajax, json, exception, struts2, invocationtargetexception

I am getting the below error when making an AJAX call in my struts2 application:

```
 org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException:             org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:243)
 org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:165)
 org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:131)
 org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.write(JSONWriter.java:99)
 org.apache.struts2.json.JSONUtil.serialize(JSONUtil.java:112)
 org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.execute(JSONResult.java:198)
 com...hony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
 org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
 com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
 org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
 org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:485)
 org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
 org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
```

The correct Action/method are executed when the ajax call is made.

I made all objects referenced in the Action class implement Serializable.

What can i do to fix this problem? I have been searching on the internet .. but no clues..

Answer (score 2):

The found the problem .. I had BidDecimal objects in my class and JSON serialization is not supported for this type. I converted it to String and double and it iw working now.

Comment: +1 I just ran into this with BigDecimal. I was suspecting they were the problem. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

solved the error by adding "includeProperties" param to the struts.xml and limiting the variables passed as the response for the AJAX call.

```
<result name="imgData" type="json">
    <param name="includeProperties"> returnResult </param>
</result>
```

"returnResult" is the variable containing the data which was passed as the response for the AJAX call.